# Should I look for the referent of a pronoun backward or from the beginning of the sentence?

Tags: pronouns

In the second sentence, if I use "it", will it refer to the "it" in the first sentence? Should I repeat "chicken consumption"?

> Chicken consumption was just below that of lamb in 1979 but surpassed
> **it** by 1980. **It/ Chicken consumption** then skyrocketed, overtaking that of beef by 1989 and eventually reaching 250 grams per
> person per week by 2004.

[image]

Comment: No. You look for a possible referent for the pronoun by working *backwards* from ***the pronoun itself***. *By default*, you then choose the first "credible" candidate noun you come to, but only if that makes sense. If you don't find *any* credible candidate noun working backwards, look *forwards* instead *(When **he** looked at his watch, **John** realized **he** had missed his bus)*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. But your example is simple. John is a human not a watch so there is no confusion. Do you mean the "it" in my second sentence is clear. Could you explain why it is clear using my example? I feel it's clear but I don't know why.

Comment: ***if it makes sense*** is crucial. Compare *When he looked at his watch, John realized **it** had stopped* and *...John realized **it** was after midnight*. Or you can come up with your own even more "complex" example involving a robot (an "it") that might look at its watch instead of John.

Comment: For your "chicken consumption" context, it's fine to use "it" to refer back to the ***primary*** noun (often but not always the ***subject*** of the verb) of the preceding utterance.

Comment: As a native BrE speaker it is obvious to me that **It** at the beginning if the second sentence refers to **chicken consumption**. Nothing else makes sense.

Comment: The first "it" isn't needed if you keep referring to chicken and not switch to referring to lamb with "it'"
"Chicken was consumed slightly less than lamb, but became dominant in 1980, and then skyrocketed in popularity, overtaking beef..."

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. @user8356, but chicken cannot overtake beef. Only chicken consumption can overtake beef consumption.